# Honda R-Type (2003), unlocks and re-locks immediately

Tags: honda, civic, locks, fob

I have a Honda R-Type (2003), I am having a locking and unlocking problem. At first, it was a case of it taking more than one click of the fob to lock the driver's side door. When I get in the car all the doors lock. 
   I could cope with this but now I cannot get out of the driver's side door. It seems to unlock when you press the fob but locks again immediately and even trying to open the door and the same time as clicking does not help. The passenger side door also unlocks and locks straight away but so far I am able to get out of that door but I am afraid sooner or later I will get locked in the car. I am able to lock the passenger side and boot door from the outside. I did change the fob battery just in case but that did not help. Any advice would be appreciated. Brian

Comment: maybe https://youtu.be/iWgG-tKbMR8

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Check for stuck lock switches on the doors? Check for a short in a lock switch circuit? Aftermarket or OE?

Comment: Firstly thank you Tony Stewart EE for pointing me towards the video. It's a more modern car and automatic but it is worth trying. Also thank you to Ben, I'm not very mechanically minded but I am sure I can find someone who is. At least it points them in the right direction. I am now able to get in the car by unlocking it with the key and switching the alarm off immediately with the key fob. Not so easy getting out still.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?